# What does a blue Wavelan plugin icon mean?

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce, colors

The Wavelan icon on my panel is sometimes blue and sometimes white. I am just curious as to what the two colors mean, or if there are other colors that ever show up.

I am running 64-bit Xubuntu 22.04.1 Lts. The current Xfce version is 4.16.
The machine is a lenovo T61, which I doubt makes any difference.

If I figure this out on my own, before I get an answer, I will answer it here by myself. But so far, no such luck.